# Filter object by array of ids

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have a list of objects. On each object I have an array.

Example:

```
"-KpvPH2_SDssxZ573OvM" : {
      "date" : "2017-07-25T20:21:13.572Z",
      "description" : "Test",
      "id" : [ {
        0: "0a477fed-8944-9f5d-56fd-c95fe7663a07",
        1: "0a477fed-8944-9f5d-56fd-c95fe7663a08"
      } ]
    },
    "-KpvPLSfotrZiBDeVOxU" : {
      "date" : "2017-07-25T20:21:33.159Z",
      "description" : "Test 2",
      "id" : [ {
        0: "6e79eadd-21b5-91cc-4b71-7ac1a42278b1"
      } ]
    }
```

How do I search for an object using the ID array as a parameter?

When I need to filter only one array I use filter and everything works ok.

```
var result = $.grep(items, function(e){ return e.id == id; });
```

But in this case I believe it does not work.

Thanks

Comment: Your data is incorrect. You can't have two properties of `id` in one object like this: `{
        "id" : "0a477fed-8944-9f5d-56fd-c95fe7663a07",
        "id": "0a477fed-8944-9f5d-56fd-c95fe7663a08"
      }`

Comment: I edited, is that correct?

Comment: It looks valid. I have posted an answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the ID's are a little deeper in the object, and they are part of an object, I think a better approach (as compared to `$.grep`) would be a custom filter. Here I have assumed you want exact comparison while filtering, based on your question. But you could easily have partial comparison with `indexOf` as well.

```js
var data = {
  "-KpvPH2_SDssxZ573OvM": {
    "date": "2017-07-25T20:21:13.572Z",
    "description": "Test",
    "id": [{
      0: "0a477fed-8944-9f5d-56fd-c95fe7663a07",
      1: "0a477fed-8944-9f5d-56fd-c95fe7663a08"
    }]
  },
  "-KpvPLSfotrZiBDeVOxU": {
    "date": "2017-07-25T20:21:33.159Z",
    "description": "Test 2",
    "id": [{
      0: "6e79eadd-21b5-91cc-4b71-7ac1a42278b1"
    }]
  }
};

//console.log(data);
var inputID = "0a477fed-8944-9f5d-56fd-c95fe7663a08";
var filteredData = [];

for (var prop in data) {
  if(data.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    var item = data[prop];
    var itemIDs = item.id[0];
    
    for(var id in itemIDs) {
      if (itemIDs[id] == inputID) {
        filteredData.push(item);
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(filteredData);
```